# In Apache, how do I redirect from a specific path and query string?

Tags: apache, redirect

I want to redirect from, e.g.,

http://mystore.com/category.php?id=123

to

http://mystore.com/categories/foo

and also from, e.g.,

http://mystore.com/product.php?id=456

to

http://mystore.com/products/bar

These will be permanent (301) redirects and there will be about a dozen of them. I don't need to extract any information from the paths or query strings, I just need to match them exactly. And I would like avoid specifying absolute URLs if at all possible.

I figure this can be done with `mod_rewrite` and some combination of `RewriteCond`s and `RewriteRule`s, but I'm already doing some URL rewriting and my attempts so far have had undesired results.

Here's an anonymised excerpt from my `.htaccess` file **before** any modifications:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule sitemap.xml index.php?route=sitemap [L]

# skip files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This works as intended. I've tried adding several different combinations of conditions and rules just before the last line, most recently

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=123
RewriteRule category.php categories/foo [L,R=301]
```

Something about that last rule causes problems. The home page loads, but style sheets, images, and other resources do not.

At this point, I'm considering just creating PHP scripts named `category.php` and `product.php` to handle the redirects.... Am I just a few characters away from the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did figure out the problem, but I solved it by changing the order of the directives and nothing else. I moved the new redirects to just after the `RewriteBase` directive and everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The resources (styles sheets, images etc.) are not loaded because there might be relative paths which have become invalid.

The problem is that the browser considers "categories" to be a folder and so the path to the resources is not valid.

A quick fix (if you are running on a domain/subdomain and not in a folder) is to put / in the path of all your resources.

For example: change style.css to /style.css so it is still included when you are on the categories page.

Comment: I don't think it's that simple. 1) I'm using a BASE element, and 2) when I type the URLs of the missing resources into my browser's address bar, I get a 404 (a 404 generated by the PHP framework rather than Apache).

Comment: The rewrite rule works only if the file DOES NOT exist. So, the PHP framework generates 404 only if the file DOES NOT exist, which means the URL is not to a valid file. Try to put absolute URLs instead and make a new test.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The `RewriteBase` directive specifies the base URL, which in my example is `/`. I can prefix my URLs with `/`, but it should have no effect. (I actually did try it for your sake. :-)) At any rate, if a URL http://mystore.com/path/to/actual/file resolved correctly before my latest additions, why should it not now?

Comment: I am not talking about `RewriteBase` in the .htaccess file. I was saying that if you need to fix the import of CSS and Images, you need to fix the URLs of the assets (in your HTML output) to use the correct path. From what I understood, is that the redirection works, but there is a problem with the resources, right?

Comment: The path to my style sheet (for example) is not relative, it's absolute. I can type the complete URL to my style sheet, starting with "http", into my browser and it either resolves or doesn't depending on whether I include the line `RewriteRule category.php categories/foo [L,R=301]` near the end of my `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Is the CSS and other resources available if you go directly to categories/foo?

Comment: I haven't gotten that far. I'm still trying to figure out why `http://mystore.com/path/to/my/style/sheet.css` doesn't work since the new rule.